# how to dis-aggregate aggregated pandas data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I want to calculate mean|sum|any user_Defined for col5 when data grouped by [col1,col2,col3] and store that values in  new column say col6.

i want generic function for all of them i mentioned above.

don't want dynamic function.

***Input data:***

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
R1    2    3    4    5
R2    3    3    5    6
R1    2    3    3    6
```

***expected_output:***

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
R1    2    3   4    5    5.5
R2    3    3   5    5    6
R1    2    3   3    6    5.5
```

I tried the following code but i didn't get expected output.

***Syntax:***

```
data.groupby(['col1','col2','col3'],as_index=False).agg({'col5':'mean'})
```

can anyone help me to tackle this.

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Use `data['mean'] = data.groupby(['col1','col2','col3'])['col5'].transform('mean')`

Comment: Thanks, It's working.